# nextjs update form values based on user session

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, shadcnui

I am very new to react and nextjs, so please bare with me and many thanks in advance.
I am using shadcn form and other UI components to create a user profile form that needs to updated after user logs in using social login (Google/Facebook/etc.). I am using next-auth and Google for signing in.

I have a profile page with a few form fields (Name, Email, phone, age, etc...). If you go to this page after user signing in, name and email are pre-populated (set as default within useForm hook).
However, if I manually refresh the page the name and email dont get updated to the correct defaults.
I see that it takes about 0.5 seconds for the useSession to update the session with current user session, but how do I force my useForm hook to re-initialize?

Here is the code

../src/app/profile/page.jsx

```
'use client'
// other imports

const formSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string().min(2),
    lastName: z.string(),
    emailAddress: z.string().email(),
});

const Profile = () => {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        //firstName.value = session?.user.name;
        console.log(`Session changed. User: ${session?.user.email}`);
    }, [session])

    var msg = session?.user ? `Status is: ${status} User is logged in - ${session.user.name} | ${session.user.email}` : `Status is: ${status} No user is logged-in`;
    console.log(msg);

    const form = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            firstName: status === 'authenticated' ? session.user.name : "",
            lastName: "",
            emailAddress: status === 'authenticated' ? session.user.email : "",
        }
    });

    const createFormField_Input = (inputParamVar, inputParamName, inputPlaceholder) => {
        return (
            <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name={inputParamVar}
                render={({ field }) => {
                    return (
                        <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel>{inputParamName}</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                                <Input
                                    placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
                                    {...field}
                                />
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                    )
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    return (

        <Form {...form} >
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className='flex flex-col gap-5'>
                {createFormField_Input("firstName", "First Name", 'First Name')}
                {createFormField_Input("lastName", "Last Name", 'Last Name')}
                {createFormField_Input("emailAddress", "Email Address", 'Email Address')}
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </Form>
    );
```

The root layout wraps everything in a Provider (based on SessionProvider)
layout.jsx

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="light">
      <body className={inter.className} >
        <Provider>
        <main className="flex  min-h-screen flex-col items-center">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="pt-28">
            {children}
          </div>
        </main>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

.../src/components/providers/provider.jsx

```
'use client'

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
}

export default Provider;
```

Tried using useEffect and a few other things.
I want to have the form fields automatically filled in with the user name and email when user is logged in and even if the user manually refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you need to update if user has its own credentials. To achieve for this you need to set values of your **react-hook-form** state inside **useEffect()** hook of react. Below, you can see the code I am sharing.

You can read more about **setValue()** method [here](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/setvalue).

Fixed your code.

```
'use client'
// other imports


const formSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string().min(2),
    lastName: z.string(),
    emailAddress: z.string().email(),
});

const Profile = () => {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    

    var msg = session?.user ? `Status is: ${status} User is logged in - ${session.user.name} | ${session.user.email}` : `Status is: ${status} No user is logged-in`;
    console.log(msg);

    const form = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            firstName: status === 'authenticated' ? session.user.name : "",
            lastName: "",
            emailAddress: status === 'authenticated' ? session.user.email : "",
        }
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        //firstName.value = session?.user.name;
        console.log(`Session changed. User: ${session?.user.email}`);
        form.setValue('firstName', session?.user.name);
        form.setValue('emailAddress', session?.user.email);
    }, [session?.user.email, session?.user.name])

    const createFormField_Input = (inputParamVar, inputParamName, inputPlaceholder) => {
        return (
            <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name={inputParamVar}
                render={({ field }) => {
                    return (
                        <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel>{inputParamName}</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                                <Input
                                    placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
                                    {...field}
                                />
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                    )
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    return (

        <Form {...form} >
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className='flex flex-col gap-5'>
                {createFormField_Input("firstName", "First Name", 'First Name')}
                {createFormField_Input("lastName", "Last Name", 'Last Name')}
                {createFormField_Input("emailAddress", "Email Address", 'Email Address')}
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Comment: if this answer worked, please mark it as solved to help others as well